# Assigning a function to a class without calling this function?

Tags: python

When I assign a function to a variable it runs the function.

I've tried changing the function to func instead of func() but i have no idea where to start.

``````````````
def deck():
  global card
  ranks = ["Q", "K", "J", "10","9", "8",
          "7", "6","5","4","3","2","A"]

  suits = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"]

  for i  in range(56): 
    for i in (ranks):
        rank = random.choice(ranks)
        suit = random.choice(suits)
        card_loop = card_loop + 1

    card = ("{} of {}").format(rank, suit)
  print (card)

hit = deck

#hit or stand class

stand = (0)

class hit_stand_class:
  def __init__(self, hit, stand):
    self.hit = print (card)
    self.stand = stand


hit_stand = hit_stand_class(hit, stand)

hit_stand.stand

`````````````
and it runs function()
````````````
``````````````

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the code where you're assigning a function to a variable.

Comment: This code contains multiple `NameError`s and won't run at all. Please post the actual code you're running.

Comment: As a general comment, I can say that functions are object. So if you have a function `func` you can do `x = func` (notice absence of brackets) and `x` also will reference to that function `func`. To "run" a function, you do `func()` (notice presence of brackets). About you code, see comments above.

Comment: Among other issues, the `print ()` function returns `None`, so `self.hit = print (card)` is assigning `None` to `self.hit()`.